# Effective way to implement the number of views on images - PHP

Tags: php

I've created a website where users can upload images and i'd like to record the total number of views for an individual image.

Now my idea on the implementation is this:

Store the ipaddress of the visitor in a session, fe:

```
$key = "view_img_".$img->id;  
if(!isset($_SESSION[$key]))  
{  
   $_SESSION[$key] = array();  
}  

$visitorIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'];  

$found = false;  

foreach($ip in $_SESSION[$key])  
{
   if($ip == $visitorIpAdress)  
   {  
      $found = true; //visitor has visited before in the livespan of this session  
      break;  
   }  
}  

if(!$found)  
{  
   //do sql update query for the number of views for this image  
   $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ") //etc.  

   //Add this ip to the list in the session  
   $_SESSION[$key][] = $visitorIpAdress;  
}
```

Now my problem is this:

I'd like it to clear a visitor's ipaddress inside the $_SESSION[$key] variable after a certain timelimit to clear resources.

The thing is:
Most of the visitors might only view the image once, and when a certain image gets old it might not be visited any longer, but the session will still exist.

Is there a way to define a lifespan for a specific $_SESSION variable so it resets itself? (equal to $_SESSION[$key] = null)

Or would there be a better way to implement this?

Comment: While you *can* do this in PHP, it's really not a good idea to do so. Just about every server has pretty powerful, reliable, well-tested logging functionality built-in, and there are dozens of mature tools out there for extracting data from those logs for the purpose of statistical analysis. I recommend integrating with one of them and saving yourself from a self-inflicted DDoS attack (just imagine, a few 28kbps modems requesting large images and your processes are hilted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are counting via sessions approach is number of unique views. If you just want to count the number of views, don't put too much brain and just run a query like:

```
UPDATE counttable SET Views = Views + 1 Where ImageID = 123
```

Populate the ImageID and you're good to go. KISS.

Comment: This wont do as that wouldnt make the views unique per ipaddress for a certain amount of time per image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that you do not understand very clear how PHP sessions work:

- Each session is individual for every user
- In terms of user, each session lives
  only until user is working with the
  website. When browser is closed, the
  session cookie is erased and session
  is terminated.
- Session might be terminated
  earlier if session life time defined in PHP settings expires

So, if you are willing to store number of views in session, you will only be storing views for current user in this particular moment. If you want to store the total number of visits, you need to use the database or another external data storage. For example, your table with images might have `views` column and you can increment it after every visit:

```
UPDATE images SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 123
```

Comment: What i want to achieve is preventing an update query when someone keeps pressing f5 to increment the number of views on an image.

So, if i understand it correctly, should i store the ipaddress of the user in the session and check its last visit in order to find out whether to update the views in the database?